# Mysql UPDATE only works some times?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code which will add 30 minutes to the mysql datetime. However this code only works sometimes which is very strange!

i.e. if i make a purposely mistake in the code and re-correct the mistake and view the page in my browser, then it will add the 30 minutes to the mysql datetime!

I am very confused on why this is happening.

this is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>

<?php

session_start();
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
$sql = "UPDATE item SET end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) WHERE id = 1;"

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

?>
```

Comment: How will an update query return rows?

Comment: @andrew-buchan, ignore the rows... I need to knwo why it works sometimes and it doesn't other times?

Comment: @PHPglue, 3 MINUTE was a typo.

Comment: @PHPglue, you said this once and you deleted it and you said it again. the field obviously exists otherwise how would it work sometimes?

Comment: You can use mysqli_affected_rows (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). Like PHPglue says check that there is a row with an ID of 1.

Comment: Your query is running every page load. Even if you have an error on the page, if this query runs before the error it will add 30 minutes. So are you experiencing a situation where 30 minutes is NOT added AND there is no error?

Comment: @andrew-buchan, I'm not stupid mate, I know there is a field/row with ID of 1 in mysql. i am looking at it. I have already said this code works sometimes which means the field/row already exist for it to work sometimes.

Comment: @KaiQing, no, the query is NOT running on every page load and that is my question is about. it will only work on some page loads and doesn't on some others.

Comment: Your query is CODED to run every page load. So if it is not, there may be a connection error before hitting that part of the code. Are you checking the server logs to see if your db is encountering a choke or failing to execute? Do you have other cases besides purposefully making a mistake to test the code? Cause based on what you provided, there is no reason why the update itself wouldn't work as is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's probably best to refrain from defensive or hostile remarks; everybody here is a volunteer.

Comment: @KaiQing, Yes, I have checked the logs and there seem to be no connection issues etc! and yes, my code should work fine on every page load but it doesn't and I don't understand why!!!

Comment: @OllieJones, Thanks, I was not trying to be defensive. I just get a bit frustrated when i ask a question and some people decide no to read the actual question and answer a question which was never asked! anyway, i do apologies if i came across as defensive.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a pending transaction.  Have you tried calling `mysqli_commit($db_conx);` after your query?

Comment: @DanWierenga, I Did try your suggestion but nothing was returned!

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* but not certain that your browser is caching the page you're attempting to download, so when you  hit it multiple times it doesn't always actually invoke the php program.

In production, pages that **must** be invoked ordinarily are hit with POST requests rather than GET requests.  Yours seems to be such a page; you want to be able to control how often this query runs without having to worry about stuff like browser caches (and proxy caches etc etc) in the control path.

Try hitting shift-reload to force the browser to reload the page. That works sometimes.

You could try adding this bunch of code to the top of your PHP program. This ugly bunch of garbage does its best to defeat caches in multiple makes and models of browser.

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But don't leave this crapola in your program when you go into production.

Comment: the issue is not from the caches. because when i look at the mysql database, nothings been added/updated there. i know its connected as it will update the database sometimes! its like it has mind of its own!

Answer (score 0):

I am a genius. I found out the issue was from missing a `;` right at the end.

should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE item SET end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) WHERE price = 200;";
```